# Android Studio Failed to resolve : com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

Sorry for the silly question but after installing Android Studio, while creating a new project it was giving me following error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
```

I added this dependencies in my gradle dependency file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But still it is showing the same error. Please suggest me some solution to rectify this problem.

```
Build.gradle for My project:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with your project level build.gradle

Comment: Yeah, sure thing Sagar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing repository URL
Add following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    ...
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
}
```

If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, use following instead of `google()`:

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'

}
```

Comment: I tried adding this on the same repositories block as jcenter() , but now it's showing  this error:
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: @Chanfool21 use `maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'

}`

as indicated in answer

Comment: As you suggested Sagar, I added maven is place of google there in repositories block, after that it's giving me strange error:
Gradle sync failed: Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0).
           Searched in the following locations:
           https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar

Comment: @Chanfool21 you need to add `maven {...}` before `jcenter()`. Then clean and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sagar, it successfully built. A lot of thanks Sir :)

Comment: Hi Sagar, need help with this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781208/error-in-activity-main-xml-after-creating-a-new-project?noredirect=1#comment88569342_50781208
If you can see, it will be lot of help